# How do I write a Rails ActiveRecord scope that combines rows and returns only latest date amongst three dates?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Rails application with a table like this:

```
id | parent_id | datetime_a          | datetime_b          | datetime_c
1  | 55        | 2013-08-03 11:00:00 | null                | null
2  | 55        | null                | 2013-08-04 13:01:11 | null
3  | 56        | 2013-08-02 17:33:23 | null                | null
4  | 56        | null                | 2013-08-01 18:00:00 | null
5  | 56        | null                | null                | 2013-07-12 07:45:00
```

I want to write three ActiveRecord scopes that return only a single record per parent_id and chooses the record with the latest datetime for a particular datetime_x column and narrows it down to rows with that datetime_x column filled. If a particular parent_id has records for more than one datetime_x column, it should only return a row if the datetime_x we are narrowed to is the latest of all existing. So the scope for datetime_a would return:

```
id | parent_id | datetime_a          | datetime_b          | datetime_c
3  | 56        | 2013-08-02 17:33:23 | null                | null
```

We get a row for parent_id 56 because datetime_a is the latest of the three date times. We get no row returned for parent_id 55 because the datetime_b for record 2 is later than the datetime_b for record 1.

```
id | parent_id | datetime_a          | datetime_b          | datetime_c
2  | 55        | null                | 2013-08-04 13:01:11 | null
```

We get a row for parent_id 55 because record 2 has the latest datetime of the three datetime_x columns. We get no parent_id 56 records because datetime_a is later than datetime_b for the three parent_id 56 records.

This is what I have so far, which does not work:
(assuming the model is Foo, table is foo):

`scope :datetime_a, ->{ select('foo.parent_id, MAX(COALESCE(datetime_a, datetime_b, datetime_c))').group('foo.parent_id').where('datetime_a IS NOT NULL') }`

Also tried this:

`scope :datetime_a, ->{ select('DISTINCT ON (foo.parent_id) *').where('datetime_a IS NOT NULL').order('MAX(COALESCE(datetime_a, datetime_b, datetime_c))')`

I'm using Postgres so any Postgres-only answers are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it this way:

```
scope :datetime_a, ->{ find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (foo.parent_id) * FROM foo ORDER BY foo.parent_id, GREATEST(COALESCE(datetime_a, datetime_b, datetime_c)) DESC) AS UNIQ_PARENT WHERE UNIQ_PARENT.datetime_a IS NOT NULL')  }
```

Comment: This solution is problematic however as find_by_sql returns an Array and not an ActiveRecord Collection which can be chained. Perhaps there's a way to do this using arel_table?

Comment: I think doing it by hand with SQL might be your only option, ActiveRecord's understanding of non-trivial SQL (such as derived tables, window functions, CTEs, ...) is extremely limited.